# I want to read serializer (new Persister)

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to parse a XML, and I have a class with some attributes. But it has not all tags of the XML, Do I need to have all attributes for all XML tags? It works for other more simple XML. Could I read only some tags? How does @Root work? and @Element?
Thanks

```
String ipString = null;
root  ip_externa = null;
InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream(); 
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
ip_externa = serializer.read(root.class, is );
ip_String = ip_externa.web;
```

the other class:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;
@Root
public class root {
  @Element
  public String origen;
  @Element
  public String productor;
}
```

My first exception is, because in the other program it was a tag.
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'utc' does not have a match in class com.example.weather.root at line 1

And if I add the old tags...
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=, required=true, type=void) on field 'copyright' public java.lang.String com.example.weather.root.copyright for class com.example.weather.root at line 1